# ActiveX control's constructor invokes second time

Tags: c#, iis, internet-explorer-9, activex, activexobject

I have a couple of questions here related to IIS and ActiveX controls.

I am developing an activeX control by this tutorial http://haseebakhtar.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/creating-an-activex-control-in-net-using-c/. I am using IE9 for its testing and VS 2010 as IDE. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;


namespace AxControls
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("42BBA00A-515E-45b5-9EAF-3827F7AEB4FA")]
    [ProgId("AxControls.HelloWorld")]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IClip))]
    public class HelloWorld : UserControl, IObjectSafety, IClip
    {
        public HelloWorld()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Starting");
        }

        [STAThread]
        public Image GetClipboardImage()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("try to get image");
            Image returnImage = null;
            if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("getting image");
                returnImage = Clipboard.GetImage();
            }
            return returnImage;
        }

        private void SaveImage(Image image)
        {
            try
            {
                if (image != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("saving image");
                    image.Save("C:\\test.jpg");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        public void SaveImgFromClipBoard()
        {
            Image img = GetClipboardImage();
            SaveImage(img);
        }

        #region IObjectSafety Members
        public enum ObjectSafetyOptions
        {
            INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER = 0x00000001,
            INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA = 0x00000002,
            INTERFACE_USES_DISPEX = 0x00000004,
            INTERFACE_USES_SECURITY_MANAGER = 0x00000008
        };

        public int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, out int pdwSupportedOptions, out int pdwEnabledOptions)
        {
            ObjectSafetyOptions m_options = ObjectSafetyOptions.INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | ObjectSafetyOptions.INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA;
            pdwSupportedOptions = (int)m_options;
            pdwEnabledOptions = (int)m_options;
            return 0;
        }
        public int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, int dwOptionSetMask, int dwEnabledOptions)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is another code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AxControls
{
    [ComImport()]
    [Guid("5DC2DE9B-8D7D-490e-A904-C8CBFFD38412")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IObjectSafety
    {
        [PreserveSig()]
        int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, out int pdwSupportedOptions, out int pdwEnabledOptions);
        [PreserveSig()]
        int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, int dwOptionSetMask, int dwEnabledOptions);
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AxControls
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("013BFB31-B3F8-4bae-B5C2-5F6D22B815E3")]
    public interface IClip
    {
        void SaveImgFromClipBoard();
    }
}
```

and that is how I call it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AxControls
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("013BFB31-B3F8-4bae-B5C2-5F6D22B815E3")]
    public interface IClip
    {
        void SaveImgFromClipBoard();
    }
}
```

1) So, when I am refreshing the page I see two message boxes with "Starting" and they appear one by another. I fail to see why. I run it in debug mode (using IIS of course + ASP.NET web project + HTML file inside it). That is my post build action

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x86\gacutil.exe" /f /i "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /f /i "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /unregister "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /unregister "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"
```

I even tried to use it on Apache Web Server - but had the same situation - constructor seems to invokes twice.

2) Many times when I am changing my HTML file in Visual Studio and run it in debug mode the changes is not visible in my Browser. I tried to clean IE history and cache with no success. Looks like IIS puts it in cache. Can it be? How can I avoid it?

3) I cannot understand the purpose of adding all that IObjectSafety Members.

**UPDATE:**

```
<html>
    <head>

        <object name="axHello" style='display:none' id='axHello' classid='CLSID:42BBA00A-515E-45b5-9EAF-3827F7AEB4FA'
 codebase='AxControls.cab#version=1,0,0,0'></object>
      <script language="javascript">

        <!-- Load the ActiveX object  -->
        var x = new ActiveXObject("AxControls.HelloWorld");

        <!-- Display the String in a messagebox ffff-->
        x.SaveImgFromClipBoard();
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the HTML code where you use the control (any `<object>` or `new ActiveXObject`). Use [IObjectSafety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/aa768224(v=vs.85).aspx) with care. It basically tells the browser that your control is **safe for untrusted calls by any web page**, not only yours. Thus, you declare that your control **cannot be abused** to do any harm to the operating system or user privacy.

Comment: More regarding `IObjectSafety`, you basically should lock your control to your own site(s), here's [how](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23438).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot TO ADD html code. Now updated.

Comment: So this, answers your question :) You do it twice: once as `<object>`, another time as `new ActiveXObject("AxControls.HelloWorld")`. The `<object>` alone is enough.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more info on your caching issue.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Now it seems to be OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we've seen your HTML code, it's clear: you create two separate objects: one as `object` tag, another one - dynamically - as `new ActiveXObject("AxControls.HelloWorld")`. Remove the the second one, and just call:

```
axHello.SaveImgFromClipBoard();
```

Don't forget about my notes on `IObjectSafety` in the comments. The best thing to do is to [lock your control](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23438) to your own site(s).

Regarding this: *2) Many times when I am changing my HTML file in Visual Studio and run it in debug mode the changes is not visible in my Browser. I tried to clean IE history and cache with no success. Looks like IIS puts it in cache. Can it be? How can I avoid it?*

When it happens next time, close all IE windows, then use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to check if there is a hidden `iexplore.exe` process still hanging in. If so, kill it (all instances), then clear the cache. The next time it should load a fresh version of your page.

If that happens, it's actually a bad sign that your control doesn't shutdown properly (but that would be a subject for a separate question).